# Can either be VS can be either

Tags: word-usage

Suppose I want to say that "'Something' can either be positive or negative". I ran into the problem of the position of "either".  For example

> Electric charge can either be positive or negative

> Electric charge can be either positive or negative

are both of them correct? What is the difference in meaning?

Comment: If you put *either* before the verb, you need another verb for comparison (either walk or run). *either positive or negative* is fine.

Comment: Both sentences are fine

Comment: I've edited to remove the confusing use of a placeholder variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both of them are grammatically correct; it's a matter of personal preference. There is no difference in meaning.

The asker is just using "A" as a placeholder variable, they aren't saying that this is an actual sentence they would use verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

> The value *A* can be either positive or negative.
> The value *A* can either be positive or negative.

Unfortunately, your original phrasing can easily be parsed incorrectly as a garden-path sentence, as if "a can" means "a canister".

There's no real difference.  It's just a question of style.